# Where to write code in Appium iOS test automation software?

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I am new to automation and trying to use Appium(Mac app) for writing test scripts on iOS app.

I have managed to load my app successfully on Appium and also used Appium Inspector.
There is a Record button which records my actions in Appium inspector.

However, my question is how do I save these recorded scripts for reuse?
Secondly, I also want to manually write test scripts using Java, but currently don't know where to write code using Appium Mac app.

I have read the starter guide on Appium website and seen some videos but cannot find any app usage related information.

Any help(links, tutorial video) will be appreciated.

P.S. I do not use Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

1. My suggestion is to not use the record feature in Appium, it's not stable and hard to maintain.
2. You can write your java-automation-code on Eclipse/intellij(and all java IDE)
   You have a lot of information on internet, you can start here: 
   [Appium - Git - Sample - java](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/tree/master/sample-code/examples/java/junit)

Try to make it run, and take it from there.
You always can ask at discuss.appium.io and see examples.

Good luck, hope it's helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your script in the same way as you used to right in Selenium means you can choose any IDE (in my case I'm working on Eclipse Juno) and then just pass all the capabilities if you will use TestNG framework then run as TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any programming language supported by Appium where you feel better.

Setup environment and create test scripts. you can learn from:

[Appium](http://appium.io/introduction.html)

[Jave Sample](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2014/02/road-to-setup-and-create-first-appium.html)